# Unable to execute the script with Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, node.js

```
String[] cmd = { "node", "/Users/pramod/Desktop/sample.js"};    
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
p = r.exec(cmd);
```

When i tried to run this code in my java program, i'm getting a exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the full path to node, on my machine for example that would be:

```
    String[] cmd = { "/opt/local/bin/node", "./test.js"};
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();
    System.out.println(p.exitValue());
```

giving me an exit code of 0 as all went well.